# Any reference for this particular mantra performed during the Ashvamedha?

Tags: vedas, mantras, sanskrit, yajna, mathematics

According to Wikipedia, the mantra (sacred recitation) at the end of the annahoma ("food-oblation rite") performed during the aśvamedha and uttered just before-, during-, and just after sunrise, invokes powers of ten from a hundred to a trillion:[2]

Hail to śata ("hundred," 10^2), hail to sahasra ("thousand," 10^3), hail to ayuta ("ten thousand," 10^4), hail to niyuta ("hundred thousand," 10^5), hail to prayuta ("million," 10^6), hail to arbuda ("ten million," 10^7), hail to nyarbuda ("hundred million," 10^8), hail to samudra ("billion," 10^9, literally "ocean"), hail to madhya ("ten billion," 10^10, literally "middle"), hail to anta ("hundred billion," 10^11, lit., "end"), hail to parārdha ("one trillion," 10^12 lit., "beyond parts"), hail to the uṣas (dawn), hail to the vyuṣṭi (twilight), hail to udeṣyat (the one which is going to rise), hail to udyat (the one which is rising), hail udita (to the one which has just risen), hail to svarga (the heaven), hail to martya (the world), hail to all.

Is there any source where I can find the original Sanskrit mantra?